# red line after BufferedImage rotate

Tags: java

Why after orientation i have red line on image?

```
public class TestOrienationImg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\IMG_7282.jpg"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
        baos =  rotateImageByDegrees(baos.toByteArray(), 90);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\v1\\xxx.jpg");
        baos.writeTo(outputStream);


    }
    public static ByteArrayOutputStream rotateImageByDegrees(byte[] image, double angle) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);

        double rads = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputstream);
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
        int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);
        int type = img.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : img.getType();

        BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, type);
        Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int x = w / 2;
        int y = h / 2;

        at.rotate(rads, x, y);
        g2d.setTransform(at);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 0, newWidth - 1, newHeight - 1);
        g2d.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(rotated, "jpg",baos);
        return baos;
    }
}
```

Original image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/elKpl.jpg]

Image after orientation(i have to compress image because of a mistake on stackoverflow:Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB).)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDArB.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `g2d.drawRect(0, 0, newWidth - 1, newHeight - 1);` uses the new image dimensions with the affine transform (orig->new) so you are not drawing a red box around the new image shape. One way to fix is to pass in the original dimensions:

```
g2d.drawRect(0, 0, w - 1, h - 1);
```

However the above may not be transformed exactly (rounding issues) to align as red border on the new image. To do that you should reset the affine transform back to default and add the red box border in the untransformed draw with coordinates in new image:

```
Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
AffineTransform prev = g2d.getTransform();
...
g2d.setTransform(at);
// ... draw image using transform

// revert transform and draw box around new image
g2d.setTransform(prev);
g2d.drawRect(0, 0, newWidth - 1, newHeight - 1);
```